# Woocommerce product displayed price manipulation using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Based on *"[Get selected variation price in jQuery on Woocommerce Variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926441/get-selected-variation-price-in-jquery-on-woocommerce-variable-products)"* answer code to one of my last questions, this code gets the users input to the product options and I'm trying to use the values to calculate the price displayed to the user, but I can't figure it out.

All of the code works, except the part above the window alert message. I have tried to add a filter function `get_price_html()` inside php tags above the alert message as well, but it shows all kind of errors.

Is it possible to just use javascript to change the price displayed?

This is the code that I am using actually:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'func_option_valgt');
function func_option_valgt() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $variations_data =[]; // Initializing

        // Loop through variations data
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
            // Set for each variation ID the corresponding price in the data array (to be used in jQuery)
            $variations_data[$variation['variation_id']] = $variation['display_price'];
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($variations_data); ?>,
                inputVID = 'input.variation_id';

            $('input').change( function(){
                if( '' != $(inputVID).val() ) {
                    var vid      = $(inputVID).val(), // VARIATION ID
                        length   = $('#cfwc-title-field').val(), // LENGTH
                        diameter = $('#diameter').val(),  // DIAMETER
                        vprice   = ''; // Initilizing

                    // Loop through variation IDs / Prices pairs
                    $.each( jsonData, function( index, price ) {
                        if( index == $(inputVID).val() ) {
                            vprice = price; // The right variation price
                        }
                    });

                    var rope_price = length*vprice;
                    document.cookie = 'rope_price_cookie='+rope_price;

                    ////////// This is where I would like to add some code to change the displayed price //////
                    $('price') = rope_price;  /// something like this, only it doesn't work :(

                    alert('variation Id: '+vid+' || Length: '+length+' || Diameter: '+diameter+' || Variantprice: '+vprice+' ||Rope price: '+rope_price);

                        }
                    }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php       
    }   
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can do this `$('price').html(rope_price);` Not sure if `price` is a tag or class.

Comment: To resume it seems that you want to set the selected variation displayed price calculated on the lenght x price. But where is the code for the length… So: 1) You should give the all related code for "length", "diameter"… 2) also you should explain why you are using `document.cookie = 'rope_price_cookie='+rope_price;` and what is it for.

Comment: The length is input by the user into a numberfield on the single product page. The diameter variable isn't actually used, I just wanted to see if I could print it in the alert.Here is the website https://seiltau.no/produkt/ssr/    The cookie was just to see if I could make a cookie :p

Comment: @designtocode $('.price').html(rope_price); worked :) Do you know if there is a website where I can see all the classes I can use in Wordpress/woocommerce?

Comment: That's great it worked @Paudun with regards to the list of classes, I haven't found any repo that lists the classes. Even if there is a list, it might get updated in a release from Woocommerce. So I'd suggest inspecting and checking the DOM in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an ID to a `<span>` element, for example `<span id="price"></span>` and then in your JS do the following:

```
$("#price").html(rope_price);
```

Please note that the `#` indicates an ID, you can also use a class selector (`.price`) which can be useful if you display the price in multiple sections of your page. You can then update these elements all at once when using a class (make it a more descriptive class then `price` then to prevent name collisions)

Comment: How would I go about doing that exactly? Where do the span tags go?

Comment: @Paudun, what does your HTML look like where the price has to go? Can you update the question with that?

Comment: Using the class selector like this $('.price').html(rope_price); worked! :D But should I not use a class selector when manipulating the price? The code is supposed to run on the single product page only, so does it matter whether I use a class selector or a specific ID?

Comment: I don't write any HTML. The code works on the single product page.

Comment: @Paudun, if you just use the default page and the class selector `.price` is used there that is fine :) that part is only a recommendation when writing your own custom HTML

Comment: I am now having the problem that the price is also being updated for the related products on the bottom of the page. The  `.price`class also applies to them. Is there a way to exclude the related products from being affected?

Comment: @Paudun, do these have a special class?