# Avoid selected variation calculated price to be reflected in Woocommerce related products

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

This question is based on [Get selected variation price in jQuery on Woocommerce Variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926441/get-selected-variation-price-in-jquery-on-woocommerce-variable-products).
I have some code that works on the single product page to display a calculated price based on user input. The problem is that the calculated price also applies to the related products on the bottom of the page. Their price is set to be the same as the product being viewed. 
 
I think the problem lies in the line $('.price').html(total_pris+',-'); where '.price' applies to the related products also. How do I fix this?
My code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'func_option_valgt' 
);
function func_option_valgt() {
global $product;
if (has_term('endene','product_cat')){
    $variations_data =[]; // Initializing

    // Loop through variations data
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
        // Set for each variation ID the corresponding price in the data array (to be used in jQuery)
        $variations_data[$variation['variation_id']] = $variation['display_price'];
    }
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($variations_data); ?>,
            inputVID = 'input.variation_id';

        $('input , #id_dropdown_one_end, #id_dropdown_other_end').change( function(){
            if( '' != $(inputVID).val() ) {
                var vid      = $(inputVID).val(), // VARIATION ID
                    length   = $('#rope_length').val(), // LENGTH
                    diameter = $('#diameter').val(),  // DIAMETER
                    ene_enden = $('#id_dropdown_one_end').find('option:selected').attr("value_one_end"),
                    andre_enden = $('#id_dropdown_other_end').find('option:selected').attr("value_other_end"),
                    vprice   = ''; // Initilizing

                // Loop through variation IDs / Prices pairs
                $.each( jsonData, function( index, price ) {
                    if( index == $(inputVID).val() ) {
                        vprice = price; // The right variation price

                    var ene_enden_conv = Number(ene_enden);
                    var andre_enden_conv = Number(andre_enden);
                    var rope_price = (length*vprice) + ene_enden_conv + andre_enden_conv;
                    var total_pris = rope_price;
                        if (rope_price != 0){
                            $('.price').html(total_pris+',-');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid updating related product prices too, you just need to make a little change replacing:

```
$('.price').html(total_pris+',-');
```

by:

```
$('.woocommerce-variation-price > .price').html(total_pris+',-');
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you that worked :) What does the > in the code do exactly?